# Selecting Text In between strings

Tags: powershell

I am trying to parse some text between strings of output.

I've tried using -split and substring but I am not getting the correct output

Here are the input file/Pipeline values

```
Please remove the following Roles:
Role1
Role2

Please remove the following Groups:
Groups1
Groups2

Please remove the following Profiles:
Profiles1
Profiles3
Profiles8

Please remove the following DGroups:
DG1
DG9
DG12
```

Here is the code I tried

```
Foreach($input in $file){
#I’ve tried the split and I get too much data after roles
write-host $input.split(':')[1]
#replace gives me too much info after roles
$input.replace('Please remove the following Roles:','')
#this loop will continuously run
do{
$input}
until{$input.contains("please*")}
}
```

I expect the output to give me Role1 and Role2, then groups1 and groups2, then profiles1 and profiles3 and profiles8, then dg1 and dg9 and dg12 then ignore the rest.

The issue I am having is in the do loop, I get continuous looping. 
In the replace, I get the roles but I also get the please remove groups line.

Comment: What is the error you are facing ? Have you tried any alternative(s) way ? There are probably various ways with which you can achieve this.  Hows does the file containing pipeline values look like ? Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. For further information, please see how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the tour of the site (https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: is the `Start of file` & `End input file` literally in the file? if not, please remove them. additionally, please format your sample data with _code formatting_ so that it displays properly.

Comment: I’ve updated the example

Answer (score 1):

*[edit since the sample data changed so very much, the previous code won't work.]*

what it does ...

- fakes reading in a text file as a single multiline string
- breaks that multiline string into blocks at the blank lines
- iterates thru those blocks
- splits the block on line ends
- gets the type name from the 1st line
- gets the items from the remaining lines and stores them in an array
- builds a `[PSCustomObject]` that holds the type of target and the list of items
- sends that out to the `$Results` collection
- gets the items for one of the target types
  you can replace `Roles` with one of the other types - `Groups` is one such.
- shows the whole `$Results` collection content
  that array can be neatly exported to a CSV if desired.

the code ...

```
# fake reading in a text file as one multiline string
#    in real life, use Get-Content -Raw
$InStuff = @'
Please remove the following Roles:
Role1
Role2

Please remove the following Groups:
Groups1
Groups2

Please remove the following Profiles:
Profiles1
Profiles3
Profiles8

Please remove the following DGroups:
DG1
DG9
DG12
'@

$Results = foreach ($Block in $InStuff -split "`r`n`r`n|`r`r|`n`n")
    {
    $SplitBlock = $Block -split "`r`n|`r|`n"
    $BlockName = $SplitBlock[0].Split(' ')[-1].Trim(':')
    $ItemList = $SplitBlock[1..$SplitBlock.GetUpperBound(0)]

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TargetType = $BlockName
        TargetList = $ItemList
        }
    }

$Results.Where({$_.TargetType -eq 'Roles'}).TargetList
'=' * 30
$Results
```

output ...

```
TargetType TargetList
---------- ----------
Roles      {Role1, Role2}
Groups     {Groups1, Groups2}
Profiles   {Profiles1, Profiles3, Profiles8}
DGroups    {DG1, DG9, DG12}
```

Comment: @DonB - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Comment: how would I go about returning the value for groups1 and groups2? I tried adjusting the match to groups: but I still get role1 and role2

Comment: @DonB - let me play with the revised data sample to see about getting all the data sets

Comment: @DonB - take a look at the new version ... [*grin*]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Awesome!

Comment: @DonB - kool! i had fun with it - and am quite glad to have helped ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

$file -replace '.+(?=Roles:|Groups:|Profiles:|DGroups:)'

Comment: What exactly does '.+(?=Roles:|Groups:|Profiles:|DGroups:)' do?

Comment: Nice. That works as well. I just have to parse that output to get each section I need at a time.